# What kind of jacks are used for lifting of framing in various situations?

Tags: framing, termite, dry-rot, temporary

I have two vertical house jacks from the local tool library, which I've used to support framing during extensive dry rot and termite repair:

[image: house jacks for framing repair]

I'm into a section where the house jacks won't work.  I need to support, and then slightly jack up, a load bearing double stud to the left of a window.  The entire bottom plate is unusable for bearing due to termites, and access is needed to the double stud to complete the work.

[image]
[image]

Notes: The window corner bears no load (it's empty). All the cripple wall is mostly new with vintage lumber. And yes, that's electrical behind the kitchen cabinets which were built into the framing.  A Realtor(tm) arranged for that lovely work.

What kind of jacking techniques are used in situations like this?

Comment: A bunch of colorful pictures...but it is not at all clear where or what part you are having difficulty figuring out how to jack. It would help if you could annotate the last picture with what part needs to be replaced and what part you need to provide jack support for.

Comment: The picture has been annotated. @MichaelKaras

Answer (score 1):

Could you support it up the same way you support a porch?

[image]

You'd want to get past that sidewalk, the base has to be absolutely secure where it sets.

Answer (score 0):

Any significant load that comes into that part of the wall by the edge of the window would be coming from the structure above the window. You could consider performing the jacking from the inside of the building. You would lay down a  timber along the floor close to the wall such that it is perpendicular to the floor joists. The two jacks can sit on this timber and the timber will distribute load across multiple floor joists. Another timber would be positioned under the ceiling inline with the one on the floor. Posts cut to length sit on the top of the jacks and extend up to under the timber on the ceiling. Adjusting the jacks up will take most of the pressure off the wall structure.

Note that jacking with posts can be tricky and you will likely need several people to help get the setup in place. If not positioned properly the posts being jacked can kick out when significant pressure is exerted by the jacks. It is also advised that full length posts be positioned between the two timbers to prop up the load while the wall work takes place. Thus the jacks would only be used till those posts can be placed.

This technique will work best when you can do this jacking as close to the inside of the wall as possible. It may still be feasible if it is positioned a couple feet from the wall in the case that there are cabinets mounted on the walls inside. This is also predicated on the floor joists, ceiling joists and the upper wall structure being in good condition and that the ceiling joists are running parallel to the floor joists.

Comment: Unfortunately, in this particular case, it's kitchen cabinets on the inside.

Answer (score -2):

Just remove rotten wood put in proper bottom plate and cut studs to what they should be and angle and whack it straight. May need sludge hammer. You can put your jack on bottom plate with short 2x4 to top plate too.

Comment: The question was about shoring/jacking, not the above.